# The process cannot access the file .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need to read a text file and store it into Db. After several times accessing/reading the file, suddenly this message appears

> the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process..

I've checked for several times, but there's not other process attached to it. Here are my code..

```
// Storing the data in a data table
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Date", typeof(DateTime)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Time", typeof(TimeSpan)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_CardID", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Status", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Type", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("L_Catatan", typeof(string)));

int i2 = 0;
string[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);

foreach (string line in content)
{
    // some code
}
```

what's wrong with my code people?

Comment: How did you check? It is possible the other access is transient – try watching the file with Process Monitor.

Comment: Do you have the file open in another editor? Like MSWord?

Comment: yes...im using PM to check it..there's no other process attach..

Comment: Might be anti-virus. But since the file system is outside of the control of your application, you probably need to write the code to deal with transient issues such as this anyway, and implement retry/skip logic. You may as well start writing this code now.

Comment: i guess it nothing to do with anti-virus because the error happen with different time of file access. Eg. sometimes, after 8 times change the content of file...the error will appear..and sometimes just 3-4 times change the content, there will be error..so it think its not.

Comment: But the point I was trying to make still stands - other processes *can* lock files that you might be trying to read, so you need to decide what your program will do *when* that happens, and implement code to cope with this situation.

Comment: ok..that's a good trick..how to to it? pls enlighten me a bit more.. :)

Comment: Also, is your current code ThreadSafe? Meaning are you sure there is no two threads racing to access the content of the file? If that is the case then one thread might have acquired a lock on the file while the other one throws the exception.

Comment: @Ramesh- im not too sure about it...but it seems like that i think

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Process Monitor (which monitors realtime activity as files are accessed), use Process Explorer (which can show you all files which have handles on them, even if they are not currently being accessed).

Go Find/Find handle or DLL, search for the file, double click on it which will select the handle in the window behind, which you can then right click on and close.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

It opens text file locked by Word at least =) Though the source of your problem will be unknown then =\

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-user file system, your locks may not be unlocked when you call methods to close the file handle.

Just retry a couple of milliseconds later.

Comment: you are right! when i retry a couple of miliseconds later, the file can be accessed for several more time before the error appear...then what?

Comment: Then you just retry a few more times ;). Wrap it in a [policy](https://github.com/haf/Graphite.NET/blob/master/Graphite/Policy/TracingPolicy.cs) [for example](https://github.com/haf/Graphite.NET/blob/master/Graphite/GraphiteTcpClient.cs#L35).